# How to decode base64 ecoded string to UIimage in swift 4?

Tags: swift4

I have a encoded string from server which is a image.
Now I want to decode that string to anything(UIImage) you can and set to a UIImageView
Thanks in advance

Comment: Convert the base64 encoded String to `Data` and then create an`UIImage`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following extension for that:

```
extension UIImage: {
    convenience init?(base64 str: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: str),
            let data = try? Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url),
            UIImage(data: data) != nil else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)!
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let image = UIImage(base64: someString)
```

Note, that for this to work, your base64 string must be formatted as follows: `data:image/png;base64,...` (or replacing `png` with `jpeg`).
If your base64 string does not have this prefix, you can do this:

```
extension UIImage: {
    convenience init?(base64 str: String) {
        guard let data = try? Foundation.Data(base64Encoded: str),
            UIImage(data: data) != nil else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)!
    }
}
```

---

#### Extra Credit

You can reverse the whole thing and convert an image to base64 string:

```
public enum ImageFormat {
    case png
    case jpeg
}
public func base64(format: ImageFormat, includingPrefix: Bool = true) -> String? {
    var imageData: Foundation.Data?
    switch format {
        case .png: imageData = self.pngData
        case .jpeg: imageData = self.jpegData
    }
    guard let data = imageData else { return nil }
    return "data:image/\((format));base64," + data.base64EncodedString()
}
```

Comment: What format is your base64 encoded string that allows you to create a `URL` from it? A normal base64 encoded string is not a valid URL.

Comment: Ah! Your extra credit answers that question. You are creating a special `data:` URL. You need to mention this in your answer. Your `UIImage` extension won't work with a "normal" base64 encoded string.

Comment: Yup, that's right. Thanks for bringing that up. I mentioned it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
let string: String = "YourBase64EncodedImageAsAString"

if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: string), let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    //use image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func base64ToImage(base64String: String?) -> UIImage{
        if (base64String?.isEmpty)! {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_image_found")
        }else {
            // Separation part is optional, depends on your Base64String !
            let tempImage = base64String?.components(separatedBy: ",")
            let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: tempImage![1], options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
            let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
            return decodedimage!
        }
    }
```

You will pass *args* to your base64 data.